# CSV returning with column name only, no data

Tags: c#, csv, .net-4.5, export-to-csv, umbraco7

I'm trying to get my plugin to export the content from blog posts in umbraco, each blog post has a contentType of 'umbNewsItem'. So following that I checked and tested the following code:

```
//This is my Controller

using ExportUmbracoBlogsPackage.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Text;
using Umbraco.Core.Persistence;
using Umbraco.Web;
using Umbraco.Web.WebApi;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ExportUmbracoBlogsPackage.App_Code
{
    public class ExportAllBlogsController : UmbracoAuthorizedApiController
    {
        [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
        public void ExportAll()
        {

            List<BlogPosts> BlogPostList = new List<BlogPosts>();
            BlogPostList = getPostList();
            string attachment = "attachment; filename= BlogPosts.csv;";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", attachment);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "public");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.CacheControl= "private";

            WriteColumnName();
            foreach (BlogPosts post in BlogPostList)
            {
                WritePostInfo(post);
            }

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }

        private void WritePostInfo(BlogPosts post)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            AddComma(post.Content, sb);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sb.ToString());
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        }

        private void AddComma(string value, StringBuilder sb)
        {
            sb.Append(',', ' ');
            sb.Append(", ");
        }

        private void WriteColumnName()
        {
            string columnNames = "Content";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(columnNames);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        }

        public List<BlogPosts> getPostList()
        {
            UmbracoDatabase db = ApplicationContext.DatabaseContext.Database;
            var select = new Sql("SELECT * FROM cmsPropertyData pd INNER JOIN cmsPropertyType pt ON pt.id = pd.propertytypeid INNER JOIN cmsContent c ON c.nodeId = pd.contentNodeId INNER JOIN cmsContentType ct  ON ct.nodeId = c.contentType WHERE ct.alias = 'umbNewsItem' AND dataNtext IS NOT NULL;");
            List<BlogPosts> BlogPostList = new List<BlogPosts>();
            BlogPostList = db.Fetch<BlogPosts>(select);
            return BlogPostList;
        }
    }
}
```

Basically it's downloading the csv, but the column is blank, there are no values. Any suggestions why the values aren't being stored in the list? When I check to see what the values in the list are it gives me 9 list items but all with a value of null. What could be causing this to happen?

### update

no exceptions or errors are being thrown, the code is running, however it's not pulling the data from the database correctly, and I am not sure why, when I run the same query in SQL SERVER Management Studio the query works fine. When I run it in my program, the query is returning the rows, because the list is returning a value of Count=9 and within each index the variable Content from the Model is stored, but the value of this is null and I can't figure that out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could it be that the StringBuilder which is trying to write the data never actually gets appended with anything?

```
private void WritePostInfo(BlogPosts post)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            AddComma(post.Content, sb);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sb.ToString()); // there's nothing in "sb" except commas at this point
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you querying the database instead of, say, using ContentService?

And your AddComma function doesn't add the actual value to the StringBuilder object, that might be it. Here's how I would do it (AddComma function and StringBuilder use seems a bit unnecessary):

```
private void WritePostInfo(BlogPosts post)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(String.Format("{0}, ", post.Content));
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);
}
```

If you want to keep the AddComma function, it could look something like this:

```
private void AddComma(string value, StringBuilder sb)
{
    sb.AppendFormat("{0}, ", value);
}
```

That being said, I assume you're going to add more columns later, right? Otherwise the whole comma thing isn't very useful ;-)

Comment: I'm going to add Title, Author, PubDate, Tags and FeatImg columns. Can you link me to the ContentService, is it an Umbraco service or a .NET service?

Comment: It's built into Umbraco and is the best way to work with content in Umbraco: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Management/Services/ContentService

Comment: Found it, thanks, I started a thread on the our.umbraco forums: https://our.umbraco.org/forum/developing-packages/77058-exporting-blog-posts-umbnewsitems

Answer (score 0):

I was missing a `value.Replace` within the AddComma method:

```
private void AddComma(string value, StringBuilder sb)
    {
        sb.Append(value.Replace(',', ' '));
        sb.Append("; ");
    }
```

Add this and bobs your uncle! sb should now contain all the values.